# Silverstripe 3 allow basic auth for controller action

Tags: authentication, silverstripe

i hava a controller, that lists calendar entries.
Permission provider is implemeted and works with the default security mechanism.

The controller has an action called "ics" that responses an iCal stream, which also works.

How can i enable basic authentication for this calendar action?
E.g.:
https://user:password@example.com/calendar/ics  ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it like so:

```
public function ics(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
    if(! Permission::check('ACCESS_CALENDAR', 'any', Member::currentUser()) ) {
        $member = BasicAuth::requireLogin('Calendar');
        if($member instanceof Member) $member->logIn();
    }
    //.... here goes the ical stuff...
}
```